# How do I get the chest in World 4-5?

Tags: mario-plus-rabbids-kingdom-battle

So I've made the path to get to the chest, but for whatever reason, the game will not let me enter the pipe. I can press A and nothing will happen (the A icon will shake in response but the team doesn't enter the pipe).

According to [this post on GameFAQs](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/211325-mario-rabbids-kingdom-battle/75730795), it's glitched as I suspected. Though, they've been able to enter the pipe, pick up the chest, and not get back, I can't get there at all.

[image: glitched]
*can't enter...*

What are my options at this point?

I've quit the game, restarted the chapter, changed my team, returned to Peach's Castle, turned off the Switch completely and still am not able to get to the chest. I'm not going to pass up on 20 orbs for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, there are multiple solutions to this puzzle. The game was glitched for that other permutation, but not for others. If I rotated red one more time, an alternate path will be made and I can enter this pipe (and go back).

[image: working path]
*it works*

Comment: There are problems with that particular puzzle. I was able to reach that back platform just fine but it wouldn’t let me return through the pipe after opening the chest. Had to Return to Peach’s Castle and come back, which thankfully remembered that I had opened the chest.

Comment: Yeah, that didn't happen to me fortunately, just getting there in the first place was the problem. Though in general, if you were to return to the castle or quit/restart the chapter, you keep your progress (as far as chests and coins are concerned), at least until you get to a save point. You'll lose that progress if you just straight up leave the game.